# Register 2 implementations of the same class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Having 2 classes implementing the same interface, how to register them?
The first registration works well:

```
iocContainer.Register<IEcContract, EcContract>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

But if I register the second class with the same interface, it throws an error. I am using Simple Injector.

Comment: Can you provide us a link to `Simple Inversion`? I am not aware of such an IoC container. _Do you mean `Simple Injector`?_

Comment: `But if i register the second class with the same interface, it throws an error.` What **exact** exception does it throw?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register multiple implementations with single interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889385/register-multiple-implementations-with-single-interface)

Comment: The real question here is: what behavior do you expect? Do you wish to inject a collection of `IEcContract` types, or do you wish to inject only one? In the latter case, please describe under which conditions you wish to inject which implementation. And please read the exception message that Simple Injector throws. It typically points to the documentation to describe why the exception is thrown and what you should do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect from the container? Which instance should it return?

If you for some reason need to resolve all the instances (in a collection), see swatsonpicken's answer.

If you need a specific implementation, you need a way to decide which one.

Some DI libraries let you name the instances and then ask the container for one of the named instances. Simple Injector [does not support it](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key).

So if you need to switch between implementations with Simple Injector, consider writing a custom factory which always returns the implementation you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this IoC container, but others use a scheme like this:

```
container.RegisterCollection<IEcContract>(new[] { typeof(EcContract), typeof(OtherClass)});
```

Maybe check the documentation for your IoC container and see if there's a `RegisterCollection` (or similar) method.